# Mathematics and love

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy

This might seem a bit misplaced, but, is very relevant to mathematics education.

The question is, how can I love someone, and teach students to love, or attempt and complete actions of love, through mathematics.

If mathematics was taught with love in mind, it might be more useful.

Thanks.

Comment: *it might be more useful* --- Aside from the issue of whether your approach could be workable in some way, your implied assumption that "it" is not presently useful enough seems strange (isn't math used just about everywhere?). But maybe this is because I thought "it" refers to "mathematics, and instead you intend "it" to refer to "how mathematics is taught". Could you clarify the problem or concern that you are concerned about?

Comment: To me what you're asking is currently unclear. I agree with @DaveLRenfro that clarification is required.

Answer (score 3):

There is research on dialogues that happen in mathematics teaching context. You might be interested in an article of Annica Andersson and David Wagner: https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/record.jsf?pid=diva2%3A1408655&dswid=4798

> ANDERSSON, Annica; WAGNER, David. Love and bullying in mathematical conversations. In: the 9th International Mathematics Education and Society Conference-MES9, Thessaly, Greece (april 2017). University of Thessaly Press, 2017. p. 382-392.

There is also research on emotions that appear when one does mathematics. This book I have not read, but might be worth looking at for further information on this: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-06808-4_2

> RADFORD, Luis. Of love, frustration, and mathematics: A cultural-historical approach to emotions in mathematics teaching and learning. In: From beliefs to dynamic affect systems in mathematics education. Springer, Cham, 2015. p. 25-49.

The first article analyses some examples of how love and bullying appear in a classroom dialogue. It might help in answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

[Not a troll]

I suggest watching the movie Conrack.  It will give you a perspective on how empathy and engagement can help with teaching (or even public speaking).  And this is coming from a harsh ex-military guy.  It's not about being soft, per se.  But some level of human connection, helps with coaching, training, teaching.

Go pay the $3.99 or whatever to stream it on Amazon (like renting a video).

Trailer:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMejIRLtTSM

P.s. Of course it is just a movie, a work of art.  So don't take it as purely a pedagogy argument.  Similarly 12 O'clock High is a movie, not a leadership manual (but it's an interesting case study, still, for leadership).